# All caps word with lagging hyphen or plus doesn't match with CONTAINS in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, case-sensitive, full-text-indexing

When using a `simple_term`ed `CONTAINS` statement on a fulltext column, I was very surprised to run across this behavioral discrepancy in SQL Server 2008 between all caps words and mixed/lowercase words with trailing hyphens `-` [or `+`, see end]. Consider this case:

```
CREATE TABLE has_hyphens ( 
  id INT IDENTITY,
  t VARCHAR(20)
);
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ft_catalog AS DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE has_hyphens ADD CONSTRAINT u_id UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (id);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON has_hyphens(t) KEY INDEX u_id WITH STOPLIST=SYSTEM;

INSERT INTO has_hyphens(t) VALUES ('foo- bar'), ('FoO- bar'), ('FOO- bar');
```

The confusing part is with the following `SELECT`:

```
SELECT t FROM has_hyphens WHERE CONTAINS(t, 'foo');

/*
+----------+
| t        |
+----------+
| foo- bar |
| FoO- bar |
+----------+
*/
```

which returns the rows with mixed- or lowercase `foo`, but *not* `FOO- bar`. Looking at the fulltext keywords:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document(
  DB_ID('sandbox'), 
  OBJECT_ID('has_hyphens')
);

/*
+--------------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
| keyword            | display_term | column_id | document_id | occurence_count |
+--------------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
| 0x006200610072     | bar          | 2         | 1           | 1               |
| 0x006200610072     | bar          | 2         | 2           | 1               |
| 0x006200610072     | bar          | 2         | 3           | 1               |
| 0x0066006F006F     | foo          | 2         | 1           | 1               |
| 0x0066006F006F     | foo          | 2         | 2           | 1               |
| 0x0066006F006F002D | foo-         | 2         | 1           | 1               |
| 0x0066006F006F002D | foo-         | 2         | 2           | 1               |
| 0x0066006F006F002D | foo-         | 2         | 3           | 1               |
| 0xFF               | END OF FILE  | 2         | 1           | 1               |
| 0xFF               | END OF FILE  | 2         | 2           | 1               |
| 0xFF               | END OF FILE  | 2         | 3           | 1               |
+--------------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
*/
```

We see row 3 with `FOO- bar` doesn't have a `foo` term alone, only a `foo-` term with a trailing hyphen, which is why the exact match doesn't hit. Why is this?

---

I've tested all other ASCII word breakers for English, and **`+` also inhibits matching.** It is alone with hyphen though, none of the other 90 characters do.

This behavior appeared for me in SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services, but I cannot reproduce this in SQL Server 2014 Enterprise, perhaps suggesting it's version dependent?

I tested with the query:

```
-- Helper table for generating ASCII characters
CREATE TABLE incr( id INT IDENTITY );
INSERT INTO incr VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), -- snip, to 255

-- reusing table despite now-inaccurate name
TRUNCATE TABLE has_hyphens;
INSERT INTO has_hyphens 
  SELECT 'FOO'+CHAR(AVG(id))+' bar' FROM incr 
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_fts_parser('"word1'+CHAR(id)+'word2"', 1033, 0, 0) fts 
    WHERE id<>34 AND id<256 
    GROUP BY id 
    HAVING COUNT(fts.keyword)>1; -- generate all 'FOO'+[breaker character]+' bar' 
                                 -- combinations

SELECT * FROM has_hyphens WHERE NOT CONTAINS(t, 'FOO');
```